# IMAP query by sender part

Tags: c#, gmail, imap, gmail-imap, imapx

I am using ImapX and C# to connect to my Gmail account.
There are two snippets of code:

```
var folder = client.Folders["INBOX"]
var messages = folder.Search("SINCE 25-Dec-2015 FROM youtube.com", true);
```

This snippet returns a couple of messages sent by youtube *(noreply@youtube.com)* and works as expected. However, if I change the query to:

```
var folder = client.Folders["INBOX"]
var messages = folder.Search("SINCE 25-Dec-2015 FROM utube.c", true);
```

I get no messages.
I was expecting that since *utube.c* is a substring of *noreply@youtube.com* the query should return the same messages.

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to search for emails using substrings of *From* addresses? (Other than filtering messages on the client of course)

Answer (score 0):

The matching logic is unfortunately server dependent.